# HttpSession.getSession().isNew() is always true

Tags: session, servlets, httpsession

I'm working with a HtppServlet and I need to use the session in order to know what I have to do (first time or not). But when I when the session it seems is always a different one, so the process always does the same it's supposed to do the first time. The code below:

```
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                try {
                       if (session.isNew()) {
                            String id=callMethod1();
                            session.setAttribute("ID",id);
                        } else {
                             callMethod2(session.getAttribute("ID"));
                        }
              }catch (Exception ex) {
                //Error handler
              } finally {
                out.close();
             }
        }
```

The thing is I need to call `callMethod2()` the second time, but it's always calling `callMethod1()`, I've tried using `session.getSession(false)` and `session.getSession()` I'm using curl to calling the Servlet and Google Chrome, does anyone have an idea what's happening or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use curl you must send back the cookies you received. The most important cookie is the JSESSIONID cookie, which identifies your session. If you don;t send it back the server cannot know that the request is part of some session.

Here is a very nice tutorial about curl and cookies: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: Well I tried sending cookies but it doesnt seem to work either I'm getting a different session

Comment: You must send the JSESSIONID cookie that you received in the response of the first request.